# How to add support for OPTION http verb to an apiResource?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have APIs like this. I have a thousand of resources.

```
Route::apiResource('users', 'UserController')
```

The problem is I need to have also the OPTION verb enabled for all routes.

I *could* manually add option route to each route, but I am here asking if there is a way to do it automatically.

> Actually the project is stalled on Laravel 5.6

I am trying this

```
    Route::options('/{any}', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        return response()
            ->status(200)
            ->withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        ;
    });
```

But actually I got this from my browser (Chrome) when calling an API using js:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest .. [cut] .. has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No so good, but resolved

```
if (config('app.env') === 'local') {
    Route::options('/{any}', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

        return response("ok", 200)
            ->withHeaders(["Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*"]);
    });
}
```